# UIApplicationDelegate does not have a member named managedObjectContext in Swift app

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, uiapplicationdelegate

I want to use Core Data in my Swift iOS app, but how can I call Core Data's managedObjectContext from within any ViewControllers?

Suppose that I want to call this method which is oft-used in Objective-C:

```
self.managedObjectContext = ((AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).managedObjectContext;
```

However, when I wrote the following code in my Swift file, it got the error: `UIApplicationDelegate does not have a member called managedObjectContext`.

```
var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
println(appDelegate.managedObjectContext)
```

Why does this get the error? Because I checked on Core Data when creating the app, the template automatically defined the managedObjectContext variable in `AppDelegate.swift` file.

So what is missing? I use Xcode 6 beta 5.

Comment: Because `UIApplicationDelegate` doesn't have such property, you've added it to `AppDelegate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way to do this is to pass the `NSManagedObjectContext` into the first view controller, and from then on to subsequent view controllers. This is what the Apple Xcode (objective-c) templates do. The object that implements `UIApplicationDelegate` creates the `NSManagedObjectContext` and it's dependancies, and then sets that object as the managedObjectContext property on the first view controller.

The reason you are getting this compilation error is that the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol does not define the property `managedObjectContext`. When you attempt to access the object that is the application's delegate:

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate`

The object that is returned is only known to implement the methods described by the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol. That does not include `managedObjectContext`.

Comment: Then why does the `Objective-C`'s code work while my `Swift` code not? Or then what's the correct port to Swift?

Comment: Again, it's recommended to *pass the context* to the view controller. Not get it from the application delegate. That is the correct way to do this. Your code is not working because the UIApplicationDelegate protocol does not include "managedObjectContext". UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate returns an object that conforms to that protocol. If an instance of that object responds to other messages, the compiler does not know that.

Answer (score 5):

You need to cast the app delegate to your project's app delegate type.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
```